# change susy $total-columns on pc view

Tags: susy-compass

Im trying to change $total-columns like this:

```
@include at-breakpoint(55em 12)
  $total-columns: 12
```

as suggested here: 
[Susy: change the number of columns according to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782914/susy-change-the-number-of-columns-according-to-screen-size)

but I cant get it to work.
I start off by setting _base with

```
$total-columns: 5
```

I designed for mobile,
but in a pc-view I want the container to have 12 columns.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Susy reference maybe try the following (Depending if 60em should be your min or max value):

```
$media-layout: 12 60em;     // Use 12 cols up to max 60em.
or
$media-layout: 30em 12 60em;// Use 12 cols between min 30em & max 60em.
or
$media-layout: 60em 12;     // At min 60em, use 12-col layout.
```

Take the defined variable and enter that variable in the mixin:

```
@include at-breakpoint($media-layout)
```